# Jquery - Tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to create a tooltip showing when rollover.

I have

HTML

```
<div id="Myicon">abc</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#Myicon").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return "Tool Tip Content";
    }
});
```

CSS

```
 .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: green;
  }
  .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;

    font: 8px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

It doesn't show up a tooltip.  Please help.

[Sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8kX9/164/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the [content option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) you also need to set the items option:

```
$("#Myicon").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return "Tool Tip Content";
    },
    items: "div"
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qga8ks4u/)**

From the content options documentation:

> When changing this option, you likely need to also change the [items](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-items)
>   option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @j08691's answer, you can set the `title` div attribute:

```
<div id="Myicon" title="">abc</div>

$("#Myicon").tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return "Tool Tip Content";
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8kX9/171/)

Comment: @abcidd - if you found the post helpful you can always "upvote" it, even if it's not the accepted answer :) Happy to have helped!